# UIImageView in UIScrollView in UICollectionView Constraints/Auto-Layout

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, uicollectionview, constraints, autolayout

I'm creating a Photo Gallery using Interface Builder. I have a `UICollectionView` containing cells as big as the screen. A cell contains a `UIScrollView` with a `UIImageView`. that you can zoom this image:[image]

Which constraints do I have to set for the `UIImageView` that:
- the image is always in the center of the scrollview, at landscape and potrait orientation
- you can zoom the image in the scrollview

I tried many options, sometimes the image is not zooming, or just a few pixels but the constraints won't allow real zooming, or somites i was able to zoom but the imageview had the wrong size and the picture was not centered